# javascript cycle tags with delay

Tags: javascript, delay, cycle

I am using javascript to cycle between 4 tags (p1,p2,p3,p4) and another tag (deck) that is updated with each p.
The part that  am missing is that I'm unable to place a delay somewhere that gets recognized.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var players = $('p[id^="p"]');
    i=0;
    (function cycle() {

        players.eq(i).load('game.php?p='+i, cycle);
        $('#deck').load('game.php?deck=1');
        i = ++i % players.length;

    })();
</script>
```

I tried with

```
        players.eq(i).load('game.php?p='+i, cycle).delay(1000);
```

but the delay method is completely ignored. Where I am supposed to place the delay to having it work?

Comment: Do you want to call cycle() not quicker than in 1s after you get data for current element? Or this 1s you only need to execute the following lines of code before new cycle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work rethinking about it. I've added also a button to stop it and a button to reset the whole loop (both front and backend).
I had to manually build the array because the elements aren't in the order I need them.

This is the working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var players = [];
    players.push($('#p0'));
    players.push($('#p1'));
    players.push($('#p2'));
    players.push($('#p3'));
    i=0;
    /*
     * cycle through the players.
     */
    function cyclePlayer() {

        players[i].load('game.php?p='+i);
        $('#deck').load('game.php?deck=1');
        console.log(i);
        console.log(players[i]);
        i = ++i % players.length;
    }
    PlayerLoop = setInterval('cyclePlayer()', 1500 );

    $("#stop").click(function(){
        console.log('stop game');
        clearInterval(PlayerLoop);
    });

    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $('#deck').load('game.php?reset=1');
        location.reload();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is definitely a significantly better approach than your original code, which I nearly went into but wanted to answer the question about why delay was being ignored. Nice refactor here!

Answer (score 1):

The delay method adds a blank callback to the effects queue. The queue executes each callback successively. So to apply the delay to a function, you have to enqueue that function in the effects queue via `.queue()`, and tell the queue when that function is completed by running `.dequeue()`.

I'm not 100% sure based on your question where you want the delay to be but it would look something like this if loading p, waiting until done, loading deck, waiting until done, delaying for 1 second, and then moving to the next item:

```
    var players = $('p[id^="p"]');
    i=0;
    /*
     * cycle through the players.
     */
    (function cycle() {
        // first load ?p. Dequeue once finished loading
        $.queue(function() {
            players.eq(i).load('game.php?p='+i, $.dequeue);
        })
        // Next load deck=1. Dequeue once finished loading
        $.queue(function() {
            $('#deck').load('game.php?deck=1', function() {
                // increment/loop once loading is complete
                i = ++i % players.length;
                $.dequeue();
            })
        })
        $.delay(1000)
        $.queue(function() {
            cycle();
        })
    }());
```

Haven't tested the code but should give you the right idea. We're queuing up several functions, the last has a delay before it. jQuery will run the first and wait until $.dequeue is called before running the next, etc.

`$.delay()` is basically just an alias of `$.queue(function() {setTimeout($.dequeue, time)})`. E.g.: it waits until the setTimeout is complete before dequeing itself and allowing the next function in the queue to run.

Comment: Ok, I grasp the logic of the queue concept, but if I use this code I get an error where "TypeError: $.queue(...).queue is not a function" and I can't figure out how to fix it

Comment: Because it's a "static" method on the jQuery class, it likely doesn't support chaining. I've adjusted the code to reflect this. You could also queue/dequeue using the player as the jquery object, which would support chaining. Eg, something like `players.eq(i).queue(...)`